# Drawing an image in a UIScrollView in a zoom-invariant way

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which displays a `UIView` which itself contains a small hierarchy of views. One of those sub-views is used to draw icons (their logical meaning are sticky note markers on a PDF page). Currently, the icons are zoomed along with all the other content. However, I want to draw them with the same size regardless of the current zoom (their correct position must still be maintained, of course). What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the [autoresizingMask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) on a UIView? Its default value is UIViewAutoresizingNone

Comment: I didn't, but it's not an easy solution. At best I'll have to calculate which portion of the PDF page to show in that constant-size view, and filter the icons accordingly. That's a lot of work, so I'm hoping for an easier solution :-)

Comment: My complicated solution would be to notify the icon views about any zoom changes and make them redraw + reposition themselves accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to set the transform scale of the subviews individually to match the zoom factor of the scrollView. So whenever you scroll, loop through the subviews and if the scrollview zoom factor is, say, 5.0, you'd set the transform like this:

```
CGFloat scaleFactor = 1.0/5.0; // 1.0 divided by the scrollview zoom factor
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
```

On the plus side, it will be centered correctly, so all you have to do is set the transform and everything else should just work (you don't have to manipulate the frame).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work - since it applies the transform relative to the center of the view, not relative to the center of each icon. So it actually moves the icon relative to the text during the zoom.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it applies the zoom relative to the centre of the view it's applied to - are you sure you applied it to the icon views and not the container view?

Comment: You're right, but I'm drawing all the icons on a single view, I don't give a separate view for each icon. However, I think I can scale the origin of the icons as well, which should work out OK. Trying it now.

Comment: I don't think that will work because the flag icons will need to move further apart if you zoom in the map, even if they stay the same size. If you're drawing them all into a single view, I don't think you'll have any choice but to redraw that view when you zoom. I don't think the performance will be good though.